# Strategies for speeding up batch ORM operations in Django

Tags: python, django, batch-file, orm

One of my API calls can result in updates to a large number of objects (Django models). I'm running into performance issues with this since I'm updating each item individually, saving, and moving on to the next:

```
for item in Something.objects.filter(x='y'):
    item.a="something"
    item.save()
```

Sometimes my filter criterion looks like "where x in ('a','b','c',...)".

It seems the [official answer to this is "won't fix"](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/661). I'm wondering what strategies people are using to improve performance in these scenarios.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ticket you linked to is for bulk creation - if you're not relying on an overridden `save` method or pre/post save signals to do bits of work on save, [`QuerySet` has an `update` method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) which you can use to perform an `UPDATE` on the filtered rows:

```
Something.objects.filter(x__in=['a', 'b', 'c']).update(a='something')
```

Comment: Nice, that looks like it'll cover a lot of cases. Will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use transactions or create the sql statement by hand. You could also try using SQLAlchemy which supports a few great ORM features like Unit of Work (or application transaction).

Django transactions: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/?from=olddocs

SQLAlchemy: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/