# Django "bulk_save" and "bulk_update"

Tags: database, django, django-orm

**UPDATE: ADDED A BOUNTY. PLEASE PROVIDE AN EXAMPLE AND I WILL ACCEPT THE BEST ANSWER**

**UPDATE 2: Explicit example now included**

[Carrying on from the same project, where I asked about bulk_create in a separate thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691359/django-1-4-bulk-create-with-a-list)
I was wondering if there is a way to essentially "bulk_save" - insert if non-existent or simply update if it already exists.

For example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    height = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a list of dictionaries with key-value pairs for these fields. I would like to filter by name, and then update the height and/or weight as these my players are still growing and conditioning. If there is no easy way to "bulk_save", a bulk update would also be helpful.

[Reference: June 8, 2012 - "get_or_create()" patch at django project](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3182)

[Bulk_update reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324779/strategies-for-speeding-up-batch-orm-operations-in-django)

Comment: I don't understand what information are you trying to update for every objects and what information you want to use to search for existing objects. Could you give us an example of how would you like to use a potentially bulk_create_or_update method? It seems to me that you can have the behaviour you want with a combination of some existing django methods, but i don't understand what you are trying to do exactly...

Comment: @marianobianchi - added explicit example. thanks!

Comment: "I would like to filter by name" sounds like an update operation. "bulk_save" sounds like a "bulk_create". I also don't know if a bulk_update is even possible in django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a variation of the update_many function listed below I seem to have improved speeds tremendously already.

http://people.iola.dk/olau/python/bulkops.py

UPDATE - apparently DSE2 is also an option.

https://bitbucket.org/weholt/dse2

Will update with speed tests tomorrow.

Comment: updated with another option. will give speed comparisons tomorrow.

Comment: did you get the speed tests?